# How to match a patter using sed and output in diff file

Tags: sed

I have a plain text file which looks like

```
*,cli-verify-aggregation-general,./link-aggr/aggregation.xls
-,stress-verify-aggregation-max-amount-of-lag-group,./link-aggr/aggregation.xls
```

I need another file which will contain only those lines starting with '-'

Output file:

```
stress-verify-aggregation-max-amount-of-lag-group,./link-aggr/aggregation.xls
```

it should not have '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible ways to achieve what you want. Assuming that your input file is called `input.txt` and your output - imaginatively - `output.txt`, the following should work:

**1. Approach using `awk` and `cut`**

```
awk '/^-/' input.txt | cut -d "," -f 2-  > output.txt
```

This instructs `awk` to match every line of `input.txt` that starts with a `-`, and print the matching line (this is the default action and so doesn't need to be explicitly specified) to stdout.

This is piped as input to `cut`, which separates the lines at every comma ( `-d ","`) and prints all fields so identified, but starting with *the second* (`-f 2-`), thus omitting the leading `-` which you want to get rid of.

The output is then redirected to a file.

You can find more information in the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) if you are interested.

**2. Approach using `grep` and `cut`**

In this rather "simple" setting, you could also have used `grep` instead of awk, with similar effect:

```
grep "^-" input.txt | cut -d "," -f 2- > output.txt
```

The regular expression to be used is the same: match a `-`, but only if it appears as first character of the line (this is the meaning of the preceding `^`).

**3. Approach using `sed`**

Finally, you can also use `sed` to achieve this

```
sed -e "/^[^-]/d" -e "s/^-,//" input.txt > output.txt
```

This instructs `sed` to process `input.txt` using two rules.

- First, delete from the input all files *not* starting with a `-` at the beginning: The first `^` still means that the following has to appear as first character on the line, but in the expression in the `[ ... ]` it means "*all but* a `-`". If such a line was found, it will be deleted (don't worry, `sed` doesn't touch your input file unless you specify the `-i` option).
- Second, in all input lines, substitute (`s/.../.../`) a leading `-,` with ... nothing (and hence remove it).

The output is again redirected to a file.

As pointed out by @Sundeep, this can also be made into a more compact single rule by stating

```
sed -n 's/^-,//p' input.txt > output.txt
```

which instructs `sed` to remove the leading `-,` in all lines that start out like this, and print (only) the matching lines (the trailing `p`), again redirecting the output to a file. *Note* that the option `-n` is important here to suppress output of the so-called *pattern space* which would interfere with what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks it worked

Comment: not sure why you say `sed` is not suitable here... `sed -n 's/^-,//p' ip.txt > out.txt`

Comment: @Sundeep yes, it is also possible (see my edit, although yours is more compact of course).